# I have the following code for referencing but it doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

```
    //Create table 1
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE manager_tel_no(manager_id VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, tel_num VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT '+256000000000' PRIMARY KEY)";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    //Create table 10
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE manager(manager_id VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, manager_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
            city TEXT(10) ,email TEXT(30),postal INT(5) )";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

I keep getting error number 150.
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What do you mean "referencing"? Your two tables here don't point to each other, and do managers have multiple tel_num values? Otherwise, do you really need that first table?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add this line at the end of the creation of the first table.

Comment: FOREIGN KEY(manager_id) REFERENCES manager(manager_id)